# AutoGenerate Package.xml_ant

Tags: ant

Has anyone managed to get the [AutoGenerate_Package.xml_Ant](https://github.com/JitendraZaa/AutoGenerate_Package.xml_Ant) working?

I have been trying on my mac and keep on getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/timothygentet-obrien/sf_ant/generateXML/GeneratePackage_xml.xml:211: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/timothygentet-obrien/sf_ant/generateXML/GeneratePackage_xml.xml:157: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/timothygentet-obrien/sf_ant/generateXML/GeneratePackage_xml.xml:81: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:listMetadata
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/Users/timothygentet-obrien/Applications/ant/lib
        -/Users/timothygentet-obrien/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

I am using a mac so not too sure if it is not working because it was built for the windows command line

Comment: I can't help you any with Ant, but am asking this as it might help others assist you. Are you using a windows emulator to run Ant and how are you setting the environments for it? These sound a bit like they may be related to things that might possibly be set in Windows Path variables but could also be set in `.ini` configuration files.

Comment: Hey @crmprogdev that's no problem... I am using the mac terminal, I am not touching windows at all

Answer (score 2):

Ahaaa what a plonker... I managed to work it out... I didn't have the `ant-salesforce.jar` file in my ant app directory, it was not being found in the lib directory... I just copied and pasted it across and we are good to go now!

Comment: @mkorman can't yet... I have to wait 2 days before I can